# Automation halts when browser popup appears in chrome for robot framework

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, robotframework, chrome

I am using latest version of chrome 53.0.2785.57 beta-m (64-bit). When I execute my test script, at a point of time when deleting a line item chrome default confirmation popup appears and test fails with following error message:

```
FAIL : 
UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Are you sure you want to delete this record?}
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.57)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)

20160815 20:47:50.143 :  WARN : 
Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Are you sure you want to delete this record?}
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.57)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)

20160815 20:47:50.145 :  FAIL : 
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unexpected alert open
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.57)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)
```

Delete popup appears as [image]

Comment: Alert boxes can be managed via the API http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.alert

Comment: I have same problem, anyone resolve it ?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem by updating my chromedriver to 2.23. If anyone facing such issue then make sure you have updated version of browser and driver.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the keyword [Choose OK on Next Confirmation](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Choose%20Ok%20On%20Next%20Confirmation) or [Choose Cancel on Next Confirmation](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Choose%20Cancel%20On%20Next%20Confirmation) to have the test dismiss the dialog. You would call this keyword right before calling the keyword that causes the dialog to appear.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, but the script does not go further after popup appears. After choosing keyword that you mentioned should be followed by another keyword "Confirm Action" but my RIDE shows exception as soon as popup appears. And one thing, the code works fine in IE.